# Cakephp 2.x - How to retrieve data from database to controller

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

HEELP! I have a table called "User" and the fields are id, name and mobile. I want to retrieve the mobile field so that the user can dynamically change the $number variable. I've been working in this for 2 days and I can't find the way to make it happen

This part is in the Reservation controller:

```
$options = array('conditions' => array('User.id' => 1), 'fields' => array('User.mobile'));
$number = $this->User->find('first', $options);

$this->PanaceaSms->username = "username";
$this->PanaceaSms->password = "password"; 
$this->PanaceaSms->send($number, "Hello there valued customers");
```

Forgive me for newbie question. If you have any questions feel free to ask. :)

Comment: How exactly does your current code not work?

Comment: Do the blog tutorial first (See http://book.cakephp.org) if you struggle with the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with -

```
$number = $this->User->field('mobile', array('User.id' => 1));
```

And for your code it whould be -

```
$options = array('conditions' => array('User.id' => 1), 'fields' => array('User.mobile'));
$data = $this->User->find('first', $options);
$number = $data['User']['mobile'];
```